# Equivalent java regex string for this

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to remove dtd tag from all the xml documents in a directory and I am trying to remove it using regex.

The following expression I am using to remove it.

```
<!DOCTYPE[^>[]*(\[[^]]*\])?>
```

But, I am getting the below error

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 27
<!DOCTYPE[^>[]*(\[[^]]*\])?>
                           ^
```

Could someone let me know the Java equivalent regex for the above string.

Comment: It is just a matter of the square brackets that must be escaped inside a character class.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  I am facing the same error even after placing the escape sequences for the square brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java you need to escape special characters with double back-slashes.

 Try this:

```
final String regex = "<!DOCTYPE[^>\\[]*(\\[[^\\]]*\\])?>";
```

Here is [DEMO](http://ideone.com/XuBFnc)

Comment: That is still giving the same error. Unclosed character class near index 27
<!DOCTYPE[^>[]*(\[[^]]*\])?>

Comment: Of course `[^]]` is not correct. In **`java.util.regex` pattern**, you must escape the `[` and `]` inside a character class. You do not have to escape a `]` outside a character class.

Comment: Inside a character-GROUP you don't need to escape. You are just missing one "closing" Bracket, that finishes the Group you start with `DOCTYPE[`

Comment: Not exactly. A backslash in a java string literal must be escaped by another backslash. There are no "special characters"; there is only one. Escaping is distinct from *escape sequences* like `\n` for newline etc.

Comment: @dognose , seems like I have closed all the brackets properly.. Pardon if I am wrong.

Comment: It seems the second closing `]` should be escaped as well

Comment: @MaxZoom Thanks, Your Demo worked. Saved my life. Thanks :)